# How can I get a user's FB ID in Parse? Can I access AuthData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

How can I get the Facebook ID of a user that "linked" their Facebook account with my Parse app? I see there is an `authData` column but when I request the class it only returns select columns. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get **facebook id** of user using **parse** own method with facebook api **FBRequestConnection**

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email"] block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!user) {
        NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
    } else if (user.isNew) {
        NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me"
                                     parameters:nil
                                     HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                              completionHandler:^(
                                                  FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  id result,
                                                  NSError *error
                                                  ) {
                                  NSString *facebookID = result[@"id"];
                                  NSString *nameF = result[@"first_name"];
                                  NSString *nameL = result[@"last_name"];
                                  NSString *gender = result[@"gender"];
                                   NSString *email = result[@"email"];

                                  NSURL *pictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1", facebookID]];
                                  NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pictureURL];
                                  //UIImage *fbImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

                                  PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Profileimage.png" data:imageData];
                                  PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
                                  user[@"email"] = email;
                                  user[@"User_first_name"] = nameF;
                                  user[@"User_last_name"] = nameL;
                                  user[@"User_gender"] = gender;
                                  user[@"user_image"] = imageFile;
                                  [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                                      if (!error) {
                                          // The currentUser saved successfully.
                                       } else {
                                          // There was an error saving the currentUser.
                                      }
                                  }];
                                  /* handle the result */
                              }];
    } else {

    }
}];
```

In this you can see I get full profile of user .. 
Thanks , May be help full for you ..